# Is is possible to call the T4 custom tool TextTemplatingFileGenerator directly in VS2008, for e.g. using an addin

Tags: t4, visual-studio-addins, t4-toolbox

I want to know if it is possible to call the T4 custom tool TextTemplatingFileGenerator directly in VS2008, for e.g. using an addin.

The case I have is that I have metadata (xml) files in the solution. The T4 template reads these files to generate C# class files in the same folder as the metadata file.

Currently I have the T4 template scan the solution searching for a specific extension and creating files. It would be nice to be able to run an add-in that calls the template with the metadata file path. Note that I use the VS host quite extensively to add generated files to the projects.

I was wondering if I can call the TextTemplatingFileGenerator directly from within an add-in and if that would allow me to achieve what I want.

Also to be considered is that I am using the T4toolbox.

Regards,
Ilias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can most certainly call the T4 service for an add-in.  You won't need to use the TextTemplatingFileGenerator, which is mostly a thin wrapper around the service.

In an add-in, cast your DTE object to IServiceProvider and then ask it for [STextTemplating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.texttemplating.vshost.stexttemplating.aspx).

Cast the result to [ITextTemplating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.texttemplating.vshost.itexttemplating.aspx) and then call the ProcessTemplate method for every template you want to transform.  If you make multiple calls, then bracket them in calls to Begin/EndErrorSession to de-dupe output.

The callback and hierarchy parameters are optional.